# Unity can't receive information from an Intent

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

I've created a simple unity project,
It should recieve a string from an Intent, 
I've also created the .jar plugin file and overrided the AndroidManifest, but whenever it calls UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage() function, the app is crashing.
I debugged the java file, and it seems to work fine, it crashes before the intent message gets to Unity...
And on top of that, the error I get  doesn't provide any useful information, I'm out of ideas here.

**Error:**

```
11-04 22:38:56.451: A/DEBUG(24464): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/nobleltejv/noblelte:7.0/NRD90M/N920CXXU3CQG3:user/release-keys'
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464): Revision: '9'
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464): ABI: 'arm'
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464): pid: 24232, tid: 24461, name: UnityMain  >>> asoscompare.clever.com.libraryunity2 <<<
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464):     r0 00000000  r1 c8f80b18  r2 00000000  r3 00000005
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464):     r4 c246e008  r5 cc87dcd0  r6 cc87d310  r7 cc87dcd0
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464):     r8 00d4aff0  r9 00000001  sl cc87d2e8  fp cc87d310
11-04 22:38:56.452: A/DEBUG(24464):     ip cc735e6c  sp c8f7f760  lr cb9f02b0  pc cbb313a4  cpsr 400f0010
11-04 22:38:56.454: A/DEBUG(24464): backtrace:
11-04 22:38:56.464: A/DEBUG(24464):     #00 pc 005b43a4  /data/app/asoscompare.clever.com.libraryunity2-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
11-04 22:38:56.464: A/DEBUG(24464):     #01 pc 005b4720  /data/app/asoscompare.clever.com.libraryunity2-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
11-04 22:38:56.464: A/DEBUG(24464):     #02 pc 005bf998  /data/app/asoscompare.clever.com.libraryunity2-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
11-04 22:38:56.464: A/DEBUG(24464):     #03 pc 0001947b  /data/app/asoscompare.clever.com.libraryunity2-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x18000)
```

**MainActivity.Java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // call UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }    
    }

    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AccessManager","OnAccessToken", "hi");
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="asoscompare.clever.com.libraryunity2" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="bfcf807c-0086-4c30-8b6e-5b42ad571eb7" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

**AccessManager.cs:**

```
public class AccessManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnAccessToken(string accessToken)
    {
        // The app crashes before getting here! (it doesn't get here)
        Debug.Log("Unity Message Received!!!! :" + accessToken);
    }
}
```